# Find IMU based on previous works

Tags: quadcopter, imu

I'm building a quadrotor robot and my supervisor has asked me to make a report of the IMU modules used in previous works, I couldn't find such reports however. Does anyone know how to find such reports or how to find out what modules they've used? It's really urgent. Thank you all.

Comment: are you serious? ... you are asking about hardware modules that were used in some unknown project at some unknown location on this planet.

Comment: "Make a report of the IMU modules used in previous works" - this sounds like your boss is asking for you to report on components used in your company's product development. There is no way for us to know anything about that. If you're trying to compare modules used on competitor products, you could look at white papers provided by comprehensive hardware component and solution vendors like Arrow or Mouser. HTH, but solicitations for commercial endorsements are off-topic. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In an academic setting, look for papers describing similar work to what you're doing, read them, and see if they mention the IMU used.  If they're describing how some hardware was used to accomplish some task, then they should include that information.